# auto assign public ip for ec2 webserver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am going to deploy Nginx webserver to run my angular application in AWS ec2 and i have 2 subnets public and private. to reach my nginx web application I will use ALB which is in public subnet, now my question is

1. can i deploy the Nginx webserver(ec2) in private subnet.
2. in which case I should enable public IP to my nginx ec2 server

Comment: Why are you using a Load Balancer if you only have one Amazon EC2 instance? There's very little benefit in using it with just one web server.

Comment: I have multiple web applications running on different ec2 instances, but in above question i mentioned only one webserver, and i use ALB to reach my web applications

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* assign a public IP address to the nginx EC2 server because:

- It should only be accessed via the Load Balancer, and
- It is in a private subnet, so the Public IP address will not work (that is, traffic will *not* be routed to the instance)

You should deploy the Load Balancer in the public subnet and the EC2 instance in the private subnet.

Answer (score 0):

> can i deploy the Nginx webserver(ec2) in private subnet.

Yes, **you can**. In ideal case the private webserver does not need any internet access.

> in which case I should enable public IP to my nginx ec2 server

The server **does not require public IP**. If you place it in a private subnet, and you want your server to access internet (e.g. to install packages or updates) you have to setup [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) in a public subnet.